# Asynchronous owl carousel in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delay, owl-carousel

I have 3 carousels on my page with the same class name.

```
 <div>
   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
     <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage1.jpg"></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage2.jpg"></div> 
   </div>

   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
     <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage4.jpg"></div> 
   </div>

   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
     <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage6.jpg"></div> 
   </div>
 </div>
```

and then on my js

```
 $(".owl-carousel ").owlCarousel({  
    navigation : false, 
    singleItem : true,
    autoPlay: true,
    pagination: false,
    transitionStyle: "fade"
});
```

This works fine, but all the carousels start almost on the same time. Is there a way to add a delay between the carousels? So first start the first one, and then when the first one is done, the second starts etc...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: how about diferent classes?

Comment: how about `slideSpeed` propery?

Comment: I would like to keep it with one class, that is why I want to see if a delay is possible.

Comment: the slider's documentation doesn't indicate any property to achieve what you desire

Comment: I tried with slideSpeed also, but not any difference. There is a delay but is extremely small, almost not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a timeout like this:

```
$(".owl-carousel ").each(function(i,elm){
  var delay = i*1000; // generate the delay somehow as you need
  setTimeout((function(){
    var $elm = $(elm);
    return function(){
       $elm.owlCarousel({  
           navigation : false, 
           singleItem : true,
           autoPlay: true,
           pagination: false,
           transitionStyle: "fade"
       });
    }
  })(),delay);
});
```

Comment: doesn't this delay the load of the slider not the slide speed?

Comment: @madalinivascu *"carousels start almost on the same time. Is there a way to add a delay between the carousels?"* - I think OP wants delay between carousals, not slides

Comment: he wants a delay between silders not one slider to load after 3 seconds,what will the content of the slider look like in this 3 seconds?

Comment: Actually this works quite fine for what I want. It adds a delay between the carousels. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Combining Phil & TJ answers:

```
$(".owl-carousel ").each(function(i,v){
var delay = i*10000;
$(v).owlCarousel({  
    navigation : false, 
    singleItem : true,
    autoPlay: true,
    pagination: false,
    transitionStyle: "fade",
    autoPlay: delay
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add an ID to each of your carousel and give them each a seperated `autoPlay` attribute. This way they will start over at different times and when you click ONE carousel it will not move the others.
Yours will tick each carousel when once is clicked.

```
 <div>
   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl1">
     <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage1.jpg"></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage2.jpg"></div> 
   </div>

   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl2">
     <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage4.jpg"></div> 
   </div>

   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="owl3">
     <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="assets/fullimage6.jpg"></div> 
   </div>
 </div>

$("#owl1").owlCarousel({  
    navigation : false, 
    singleItem : true,
    autoPlay: true,
    pagination: false,
    transitionStyle: "fade",
    autoPlay: 10000;
});

$("#owl2").owlCarousel({  
    navigation : false, 
    singleItem : true,
    autoPlay: true,
    pagination: false,
    transitionStyle: "fade",
    autoPlay: 7000;
});

$("#owl3").owlCarousel({  
    navigation : false, 
    singleItem : true,
    autoPlay: true,
    pagination: false,
    transitionStyle: "fade",
    autoPlay: 5000;
});
```

Comment: This is something I want to avoid actually. But thanks anyway

Comment: Aw, okay. Sorry then :(